# DisplayAll in jsp

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a database set up with hibernate. In my jsp page I display a form to insert values, and I pass those values into my java class, which then saves that entry into a database, which works fine, but when I want to display the data from my table it gives me the error

```
org.apache.jasper.el.JspPropertyNotFoundException: /list_object.jsp(45,0) '${objectManager.allObjects}' The class 'ObjectManager$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b2d7311' does not have the property 'allObjects'
```

For the line

```
<c:forEach var="object" items="${objectManager.allObjects}">
```

in

```
<c:forEach var="object" items="${objectManager.allObjects}">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${object.objectID}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${object.objectRule}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I think this is a problem with the Hibernate-Proxy-Object, but I run the same operation with another table/bean with the line

```
<c:forEach var="object" items="${objectManager.allLayouts}">
```

and it runs perfectly fine. I checked my xml config files and my hbm.xml config and the bean was set up correctly. I don't know where the error originates from, and why it would work fine for one Spring-bean and not for the other

EDIT:

```
 @Transactional
 public class ObjectManager{
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      public void saveObject(Objects object){
           getCurrentSession().save(object);
      }

      @SupressWarnings("unchecked")
      public Iterable<Objects> getAllObjects(){
            return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Objects.class)
                   .addOrder(Order.desc("objectID"))
                   .list():
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is pretty self explanatory.

There is no `getAllObjects()` method for the `objectManager` object.

Your *working* example is using a different method - `getAllLayouts()`.

Comment: ObjectManager is my class that contains getAllObjects() method just like LayoutManager contains getAllLayouts(). getAllLayouts works because I was calling allLayouts with layoutManager, which is why I don't understand why allObjects won't work with objectManager, which contains getAllObjects

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `ObjectManager` class structure? Just signatures should suffice, we don't need to see the actual method contents. Could it be possible that your method is not scoped `public`?

Comment: Solved the problem, I was calling the wrong bean when I included the spring bean